# How should I share API definitions between the server and the client, both in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I've got a server (TypeScript, NestJS) and a client (TypeScript, Angular) and they talk to each other.

Currently I have the API repsonse DTO classes defined in the server to output, and again in the client to decode the responses into a class. This smells.

What's a good way to share the API response DTOs between the two projects (or, if this isn't a good idea, why)?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to change the API response format for the server, and then have the client not build because things have changed. It's still in very early beta at the moment, and I control deployment of both client and server so a fair amount of these changes are breaking.

They're currently in two git repositories, but if needed that can change.

Comment: [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) can generate TypeScript clients from Swagger, so if you generate Swagger in your NestJS server, you can generate the types and client code to call those APIs.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I am in the same situation and the problem is that the DTO on the server has some fields as Mongoose ObjectId while on the client would be a simple string.

Comment: To my shame, I'm copying the code between my two repositories :( It's fine so far, but I'm the only dev on the project so I can't get too far out of sync (being the only dev is, ironically, also the reason I haven't had time to look into a real solution for this!)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to achieve this - but they need you to think about the structure of the project (and need some work).

1. Using the monorepo approach, by utilizing tools such as [NX (here's a getting started)](https://nx.dev/getting-started/nx-and-angular), you can have your types/models in one place and share them between your frontend and backend. There's also other tools such as [Turborepo](https://turborepo.org/docs)
2. Another way would be to make a shared repository of types and share them between both your backend and frontend [using git submodules](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule).